# Math with several lists in python

Tags: python

Im trying to obtain all possible combinations of three different lists in python

say I have three lists

```
A = [2,3,4,7,9]
B = [2,3,5]
C = [1,2]
```

I want to return all combinations for which is true A[i]+B[j]-C[k] == 3

```
D = [[i,j,k] for i in A for j in B for k in C]
```

which gives me all combinations in a list format, but how to go on from here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to check each of the combinations to see if it matches your criteria.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [(a,b,c) for a,b,c in product(A,B,C) if a + b - c == 3]
[(2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 2, 2)]
```

Comment: Though I'm not sure if it's OP requirement, but may be you should change `(a,b,c)` to `[a,b,c]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `if i+j-k == 3`. You don't want `A[i]`, etc., as that indexes each `list`, while `i`, `j`, and `k` are already the elements themselves.

```
D = [[i,j,k] for i in A for j in B for k in C if i+j-k == 3]
```

You should also look into `itertools.product` to avoid nesting like this:

```
import itertools
D = [[i,j,k] for i,j,k in itertools.product(A, B, C) if i+j-k == 3]
```

Comment: Yes, I see now. I'll be getting new glasses in a week or two, sorry.

Comment: I have no idea which one runs faster, but the one with `itertools` is easier to write for n lists, especially if you put them all into a container, at which point you can just do `itertools.product(*container)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the condition at the end:

```
>>> D = [[i,j,k] for i in A for j in B for k in C if i + j - k == 3]
>>> D
[[2, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2]]
```